# How to incorporate the train split function in a pipeline

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to implement a linear regression predictive model in a pipeline. In the pipeline, i have added the OneHotEncoder and the Random forest model. However i would also like to add the train split function too just after the OneHotEncoder in the pipeline.

As i am not able to split the data after the Onehotencoder, i am getting the following error:

```
ValueError: Found unknown categories ['G'] in column 2 during transform
```

my current code is given below:

```
df1=mydata.copy()

X = df1.drop(['A'], axis=1)
y = df1.A
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, random_state=42)
#Pipeline
column_trans = make_column_transformer(
    (OneHotEncoder(), ['B', 'C','D', 'E','F']),
    remainder='passthrough')
reg_mod = RandomForestRegressor(max_depth=4, max_features='sqrt', min_samples_leaf=2,
                      min_samples_split=5, n_estimators=200, random_state=42)

pipe = make_pipeline(column_trans,reg_mod)

model = pipe.fit(X_train, y_train)

predictions = model.predict(X_test)
print (r2_score(y_test, predictions))

ValueError: Found unknown categories ['G'] in column 2 during transform
```

Comment: I think it means that there is a label ````G```` which is not in the training set but appears in the test set and its unknown for the ````onehotencoder````.

Comment: Yes.. is there a way it should be dynamic

Comment: Make sure that all the categorical samples are available in test and train datasets by using stratified shuffle split rather than simple random split, Refer - https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.StratifiedShuffleSplit.html

Comment: if any case in my unknown data-set which i need to predict has a new category, then at that case how would i proceed

Comment: If you are expecting a new category in the future which the model was not fitted on , then I don't see any other option other than retraining for the new category.